# NodeJS Sqlite WHERE IN Query Stament with dynamic Parameter (?)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I use dynamic parameters for my SQLITE statments in node. For example `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.id = ?`. This all works quite well. But with a WHERE IN query I always get no results. Which indicates that it is misinterpreting the dynamic parameter. **Here is my code:**

```js
    getModelsByBrandId: (ids_array) => {
        const ids = ids_array.toString();
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM models WHERE brand_id IN (?)";
        const  params = [ids];

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
            db.all(sql, params, async (err, rows) => {      
                if (err) {
                  reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(rows)
                }
            });
        });                
    },
```

I had already tried passing the array but also a string (`array.toString()`). Unfortunately, neither of these returned any results.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong and what do I have to do to make the `WHERE IN` query work?

Thanks in advance! Max

Answer (score 4):

```
getModelsByBrandId: (ids_array) => {
    const placeholders = ids_array.map(() => '?').join(',');
    const params = ids_array;
    const sql = "SELECT * " 
              + "FROM models "
              + "WHERE brand_id IN (" + placeholders + ")";

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        db.all(sql, params, async (err, rows) => {      
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            } else {
              resolve(rows)
            }
        });
    });                
},
```

Should send a query like

```
getModelsByBrandId([1, 2, 3]);
// sql = "SELECT * FROM models WHERE brand_id IN (?,?,?)"
// params = [1, 2, 3]
```

---

#### ** EDIT **

I needed somewhat the same feature, where I was dealing with raw queries. So, instead of writing everything, and as a personal exercise, I wrote a template function that handled SQL parameters like these.

```
import { sql } from "./sql.template";

const brand_ids = [1, 2, 3];

const [ query, params ] = sql`
  SELECT *
  FROM models
  WHERE brand_id IN (${brand_ids})
`;

console.log({ query, params });
// { query:"SELECT * FROM models WHERE brand_id IN (?,?,?)", params:[1, 2, 3] }
```

Source available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sql-template-74ilud?file=/src/index.js:0-150).

Answer (score 0):

#### What you should not do!

Is to write the statement without "dynamic parameter" like:

```js
const sql = "SELECT * FROM models WHERE brand_id IN (" + ids_array.toString() + ")";
const  params = [];
```

Why? See the comments below...

Comment: Please don't build queries with string concatenation. It makes apps vulnerable to SQL injections and may lead to syntactically incorrect queries.

Comment: @derpirscher Regular you are right! And be sure i dont build queries with string concat. But in this case it doesnt matter because the OP pass an array to the function and toString() make a comma seperated string. I dont thing it is possible in this case to make a sql injection.

Comment: ok, it seems it is possible if the array have only one value. But im sure the OP check the array before he pass into the function ... ;-)

Comment: What happens if `ids_array` is an array of string? Your query gets invalid ... Or worse, it's a wide open door for sql injections ... https://jsfiddle.net/0fuy5q2L/2/

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, as I said, it is not the best solution. Because I don't know what happened to the array before. But what solution would you have for this case?

Comment: "*it is not the best solution*" is quite an understatement. It's dangerous and error prone ...

Comment: @derpirscher Then I will delete my answer. But I am curious what you can contribute to the solution. But I assume you don't know a better solution, do you? :-)

Comment: The simplest is probably to expand the query in a way, you add a `?` for every element in `ids_array` and let the library handle the rest. Ie you don't have `WHERE id in (?)` but `WHERE id in (?,?,?,...?)`

Comment: And depending on the library used, the library may even handle array correctly. I don't know for SQLITE, but the mysql library definitively handles that correctly (and also escapes the values correctly)

Comment: @derpirscher Sounds good and right! I don't know how I would do that. If you post your answer here, I will definitely give you my upvote! Das mein ich ernst ;-)

Comment: Seems like Yanick Rochon already did ...

Comment: @derpirscher Looks like it! "Was für ein Mist!" Thanks for the discussion and yes my solution was not a good one. See you soon ...

Comment: @MaikLowrey I edited my answer with some goodies, if you are interested.